# How to change mime type to text/html in rails 3?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, mime-types

Rails 3 defaults to Content-Type: text/plain

I'm trying to send and HTML email. How do I adjust the mime type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding `.html` before the extension of your view template should work.

```
app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about ActionMailer? Name your view files like this:

```
app/views/mailer_name/method_name.text.plain.erb
app/views/mailer_name/method_name.text.html.erb
```

Then, in text.plain, have a plain-text version of your HTML email.

Comment: You're duplicating the extensions here, just method_name.text.erb will do... additionally you'll need a `respond_to` in your Mailer class's method which will cause it to send a multi-part email containing both the text and html components.